# How the non-existance of free quarks is explained by asymptotic freedom?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, interactions, quarks, strong-force

It is written in page 527 of Schwartz Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model book that

> Due to asymptotic freedom, free quarks do not exist.

I don't understand how asymptotic freedom explains this phenomena?